# Changing parameter value in href based on selector text

Tags: jquery

i am coding an application form of a music program. The program is applied based on date. The currently static content and there a lot of dates for each program. I need to find a way to code the "apply button" so it would get date and program in the parameters "dynamically". here is my jsfiddle

```js
$('a.ApplyNowDate').attr('href', function() {
  return 'http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&date=' + $(this).prev().text() + '/';
})
```

```css
.ApplyNowDate,
.ApplyNowDate:hover {
  background: #e91e63;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Programme</strong>&nbsp;<span class="TheProgramme">Reggae</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Venue</strong> School of Rock</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2019</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – August
          <br>
          <em>22 Jul – 16 Aug 2019</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=22 Jul - 16 Aug 2019">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2020</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – September
          <br>
          <em>20 Jul – 14 Sep 2020</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=20 Jul - 14 Aug 2020">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Programme</strong>&nbsp;<span class="TheProgramme">Blues</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Venue</strong> School of Rock</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2019</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – August
          <br>
          <em>1 Jul – 10 Aug 2019</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=22 Jul - 16 Aug 2019">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2020</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – September
          <br>
          <em>8 Jul – 14 September 2020</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=20 Jul - 14 Aug 2020">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have successfully get the date in the URL parameters. How do i get the program? what jQuery selector should i use? is it even possible?

Comment: Where does the program come from? If it's an input field, use `.val()` to get its value.

Comment: Show a sample of the HTML, and explain what the URL should be.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to link the jsFiddle URL. The HTML block is too long and afraid I would confuse people. But I have included the jsFiddle link now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).closest(".vc_tta-panel-body").find(".TheProgramme").text()`

`$(this).closest(".vc_tta-panel-body")` goes up to the DIV that contains both the link and the program. Then `.find(".TheProgramme")` searches for the program in the DIV.

```js
$('a.ApplyNowDate').attr('href', function() {
  return 'http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=' + $(this).closest(".vc_tta-panel-body").find(".TheProgramme").text() + '&date=' + $(this).prev().text() + '/';
})
```

```css
.ApplyNowDate,
.ApplyNowDate:hover {
  background: #e91e63;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Programme</strong>&nbsp;<span class="TheProgramme">Reggae</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Venue</strong> School of Rock</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2019</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – August
          <br>
          <em>22 Jul – 16 Aug 2019</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=22 Jul - 16 Aug 2019">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2020</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – September
          <br>
          <em>20 Jul – 14 Sep 2020</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=20 Jul - 14 Aug 2020">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="vc_tta-panel-body">
  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Programme</strong>&nbsp;<span class="TheProgramme">Blues</span>
        <br>
        <strong>Venue</strong> School of Rock</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2019</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – August
          <br>
          <em>1 Jul – 10 Aug 2019</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=22 Jul - 16 Aug 2019">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Schedule for 2020</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>July – September
          <br>
          <em>8 Jul – 14 September 2020</em> <a class="ApplyNowDate" href="http://schoolofofrock.com/?programme=Reggae&amp;date=20 Jul - 14 Aug 2020">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Barmar for the great solution and I learnt something new today! Awesome